# Npgsql + Entity Framework + Edmx with column type bit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I have been using Npgsql with Entity Framework + .net, while using column type as bit in the ssdl part of edmx file, its throwing an error like "The type bit is not a primitive type" .

Can anyone tell me how to use bit type with edmx file.

Thanks.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: No, I have changed the datatype to bool instead

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `bit` for boolean types? If so, you need to change your `bit` type to `bool` in your database.

If not, you need to use `smallint` in Entity Model.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the database does not support a certain datatype you want to store.