# data type 'bit' is not supported for Entity Framework version using postgresql

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql, ef-database-first

I'm stuck updating my .NET Framework 4.8 app, using Entity Framework 6 with a PostgreSQL database which is in the Amazon Aurora Cluster ecosystem.
I'm using the Database First Approach and have Npgsql in place as data provider. I also added the [Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration) extension to use the Data Model Wizard.

Once clicking through the Entity Data Model Wizard, the generated .edmx shows warnings:

> Errors Found During Generation:
> warning 6005: The data type 'bit' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'column1' in the table 'table1' was excluded.

Everything works fine, but all bit type columns are skipped and not included in the model since bit is no primitive postgresql datatype.

I'm not able to modify the database structure, since my app just connects to that existing ecosystem.

I already tried to modify the .edmx file manually, adjstusting the SSDL / CSDL / Mapping content and the model itself by adding a bool type for all bit datatypes. But that's not working - results into:

> Error 40: The Type bool is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification

[Npgsql + Entity Framework + Edmx with column type bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137996/npgsql-entity-framework-edmx-with-column-type-bit) is no solution, since I'm not able to modify the database.

Is there any way to specify a custom mapping for this?
Really appreciate any help solving that.

Versions:

|  | Version |
| --- | --- |
| .NET Framework | 4.8 |
| EntityFramework | 6.4.4 |
| EntityFramework6.Npgsql | 6.4.3 |
| PostgreSQL (within Amazon Aurora Cluster) | 13.7 |

Edit: Added the notes that I'm dealing with an Amazon Aurora Cluster with PostgreSQL

Comment: Hmm, `boolean`  **is** a  "primitive" type in Postgres.

Comment: Also tried naming it **boolean**, same error. But the main idea would be to have that stuff auto generated for updates etc. So I'd be super happy to avoid manual editing the .edmx file.

Comment: `bit` isn't a PostgreSQL type - it's a SQL Server type (PG has boolean). You'll need to find the reference to `bit` and fix it.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I'm in an Amazon Aurora Cluster - that's why I'm dealing with the bit datatype. I'm trying to extend the support, converting that bit into boolean on the model level

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research, I've found out that there is no way to achieve this. I ended up pushing a request for altering the whole database structure.